# Query running slowly in PHP page and faster in PHP MY ADMIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query that is running slowly in my php page:

```
SELECT DATE(p.mydate) as `Dataa`, COUNT(DISTINCT p.terminalid) as Used_terminal 
FROM pay p, terminals t
WHERE t.tType='Self-service terminal' AND p.IDTerminal=t.TID AND p.Dataime BETWEEN '2017-10-01 00:00:00' and '2017-10-10 00:00:00'
Group by `Data`
```

It runs for about  0.4172 seconds in PHP MY ADMIN and about 12 seconds in my php page that is to much. I have tried with another simple query and it works fine on my php page so i must change something in my query but i can't understand what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since this is a working query, and you want optimization, you may want to ask this in [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: May be they are located on different hosts? Your phpadmin on other host then script

Comment: @Stepchik located on the same host.

Comment: How did you get 12 seconds? Did you add some time label before query and after and log difference or it's total script execution time?

Did you use indexes?

Comment: @Stepchik only the query 12 seconds, result in the logs i have.  I'm using some indexes but maybe not understanding witch one should be indexed for this kind of query

Comment: Have you tried to `EXPLAIN` your query?

Comment: Use `JOIN` instead

Comment: @DiéfaniFavaretoPiovezan _Use JOIN instead_ why?

Comment: When running on phpmyadmin it won't make any difference but in the web page it probably will, specially if you are using php 5 or 7 and mysql 5.1 and up.  I had the same issue a lot of times.